# Splitting a list of lists into multiple lists by length of sub list

Tags: python, list, sorting, sublist

I have a sorted list that looks like:

```
tokens = [[46565], [44460], [73, 2062], [1616, 338], [9424, 24899], [1820, 11268], [43533, 5356], [9930, 1053], [260, 259, 1151], [83, 31840, 292, 3826]]
```

and I want to split it into distinct lists by the length of sublist like so:

```
a = [[46565], [44460]]
b = [[73, 2062], [1616, 338], [9424, 24899], [1820, 11268], [43533, 5356], [9930, 1053]]
c = [[260, 259, 1151]]
d = [[83, 31840, 292, 3826]]
```

I'm having some trouble trying to do this without just looping over the entire original list and checking the length of each sublist.

I thought perhaps I could do something with:

```
lengths = list(map(len,tokens))

for k, v in zip(lengths, tokens):
    <SOME CODE HERE>
```

any ideas?

Comment: [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about as efficient as you can get, and pretty simple:

```
tokens = [
    [46565], [44460], [73, 2062], [1616, 338], 
    [9424, 24899], [1820, 11268], [43533, 5356], 
    [9930, 1053], [260, 259, 1151], 
    [83, 31840, 292, 3826]
]
groups = {}
for sublist in tokens:
    groups.setdefault(len(sublist), []).append(sublist)
```

After this runs, `groups` will be a dictionary with keys for the length of the sublist and values that are all the sublists of that length, in the order they were found in `tokens`. You can then assign those entries to named variables if you want (`a = groups[1]`, etc.), but for most workflows you will do better to work directly with the `groups` dictionary, since that generalizes the solution (What if there's a 0-length list? What about a 15-item list?).

There is no way to do this with a one-line list comprehension because you need to cluster each input value differently. For aggregation (like this), the best solution is almost always to run a `for` loop over your input data and create or update entries in an output dictionary.

The `.setdefault` method of dictionaries is also very useful for this pattern, since it saves you the trouble of checking whether the entry exists before you update it. Alternatively, you could use `groups = collections.defaultdict(list)`, then just update it via `groups[len(sublist)].append(sublist)`.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

One way is `sorted` with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
[list(v) for _ ,v in groupby(sorted(tokens, key=len), key=len)]

[[[46565], [44460]],
 [[73, 2062],
  [1616, 338],
  [9424, 24899],
  [1820, 11268],
  [43533, 5356],
  [9930, 1053]],
 [[260, 259, 1151]],
 [[83, 31840, 292, 3826]]]
```

Comment: or `{k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(tokens, key=len), key=len)}`

Answer (score 0):

Not the most optimal way to do it, but follows most of it.

```
import string

alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase

tokens = [[46565], [44460], [73, 2062], [1616, 338], [9424, 24899], [1820, 11268], [43533, 5356], [9930, 1053], [260, 259, 1151], [83, 31840, 292, 3826]]

numbering = {(ord(k)-96):k for k in alphabets}
output = {k:[] for k in alphabets}


lengths = list(map(len,tokens))

for k, v in zip(lengths, tokens):
    output[numbering[k]].append(v)

print(output)
```

This is the output:

```
{'a': [[46565], [44460]], 'b': [[73, 2062], [1616, 338], [9424, 24899], [1820, 11268], [43533, 5356], [9930, 1053]], 'c': [[260, 259, 1151]], 'd': [[83, 31840, 292, 3826]], 'e': [], 'f': [], 'g': [], 'h': [], 'i': [], 'j': [], 'k': [], 'l': [], 'm': [], 'n': [], 'o': [], 'p': [], 'q': [], 'r': [], 's': [], 't': [], 'u': [], 'v': [], 'w': [], 'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': []}
```